# cast from WNDPROC to LONG

Tags: c++, winapi

```
static LRESULT CALLBACK wndProcNew(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}

int CALLBACK wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInst,HINSTANCE,PWSTR szcmdLine,int cmdShow){
    using namespace std;
    Pixel pix;
    LONG tmp = SetWindowLong(pix.getWnd(), GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG)wndProcNew);
    return 0;
}
```

I want to change the window procedure. mingw throws an error:

> error: cast from 'LRESULT (*)(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)' {aka 'long
> long int (*)(HWND__*, unsigned int, long long unsigned int, long long
> int)'} to 'LONG' {aka 'long int'} loses precision [-fpermissive]    21
> |     LONG tmp = SetWindowLongW(pix.getWnd(), GWLP_WNDPROC,
> (LONG)wndProcNew);

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: you need use `SetWindowLongPtr` and cast to `LONG_PTR`

Comment: That's how we used to subclass controls, literally decades ago. See [Subclassing Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/subclassing-overview) to learn how we are subclassing controls since Windows XP/Server 2003.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On 64-bit Microsoft Windows, pointers (including function pointers) have a size of 64 bits, whereas a variable of type `long` or `LONG` has a size of 32 bits. Therefore, a variable of that size is unable to represent the value of a pointer.

If you want to set 64-bit values, I recommend that you use [`SetWindowLongPtr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowlongptra) instead of `SetWindowLong`.